# SMS messages are coming slower after moving from S8+ to S10

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Recently I moved from my Samsung Galaxy S8+ to Samsung Galaxy S10.

One thing that caught my attention is the time required for an SMS to arrive after being sent by a service that uses SMS messages to 2FA logins.

On S8+ the SMS would come about the same moment I click the button on the website. On S10 that process takes some three seconds.

Is that normal? Maybe S10 is a smaller device with less powerful hardware to talk with the provider. Maybe the same SIM card* that I have been using for the last six years needs to be replaced. Or such.

<sup>*</sup> This card originally came in the standard size. It had been cut down to the nano size.

Comment: Modern SIM cards are not only smaller but usually use different voltages. As you found out most Smartphones are backward compatible, however I strongly recommend to replace your SIM with a current one. I don't think the SIM card has an effect on the SMS reception, however SMS reception is done by the radio subsystem - a system that is mostly a black box. Therefore you never know what effect changing the SIM card has.

Comment: One reason i can think of is to combat SMS Bomber services... I imagine the device is actually doing a check for anymore incoming SMS that might be the exact same... The peeiod that it checks for another SMS sounds around 3 seconds.